# __attribute__((aligned)) - gcc

Tags: gcc, attributes, alignment, memory-alignment

How will gcc set the alignment for variable/field with

```
 __attribute__((aligned))
```

What about different gcc versions/ different platforms?

Testing code:

```
int main() {
printf("%d\n", (__alignof__(char __attribute__ ((aligned)) )) );
}
```

For x86, gcc 3.4, 4.1, 4.3 I got 16.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html, talks about aligned attribute first. As to exact alignment on different platforms -- hmm...